# How To Test BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver In Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

I want to check the `BROADCAST RECEIVER` with Action `BOOT_COMPLETED` in the `emulator`.

Is there any way to check that broadcast receiver in emulator ? How can i restart emulator to check that receiver ? is there any direct command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using adb to send the broadcast and it did not work for me on Android O. I got a security exception. I had to reboot the emulator, which I actually did by holding down the power button icon and choosing reboot from the GUI.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is no Power Button in Emulator like Devices have,So

*To stop an emulator instance, just close the emulator's window.*

And To `Start/Restart` it **Start from AVD Manager of Eclipse** and Your BroadcastReceiver with BOOT_COMPLETE action will get called *for sure*

You can start AVD another way also, From `CMD` *go to Tools of AndroidSDK* and give this commmand `E:\android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator -avd AVDNAMEHERE`

To **Send Broadcast from CMD** you can use this Command.

> adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

---

Read more about Android Emulator : [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) and [Using Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Comment: ```adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED``` is fully sufficient for a device reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately, sending that broadcast causes my Nexus 5 to *really* reboot instead of just broadcasting that message. As a result, the debugger is disconnected. /sigh sending broadcasts like this should accessible to the dev in an easier-to-use manner :-( :-(

Comment: Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x400000 pkg=com.myapp.package }
Security exception: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=11148, uid=2000

Comment: how to get adb in my path?  I installed android studio 4 and it's not found anywhere but except eclipse logs that it is running that command.

Comment: @akshaybhange use `adb root` before it

Answer (score 44):

Basically this is what you have to do to Emulate the Boot Complete in Android Emulater while is is running:Assuming you are a ***Windows*** User.The same applies for ***Linux***

**STEPS**:On your Console type

1. adb shell
2. am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

That is all folks. **see the diagram below for a detailed illustration**.

[image]

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: If you want a one liner, it's `adb shell su -c am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: since the answer didn't included the line for `Windows OS`, use this- `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: Getting 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=203
99, uid=2000

Comment: For those with SecurityException, try adb root before adb shell

Comment: with add root getting->adbd cannot run as root in production builds

Answer (score 40):

Some apps may misbehave if BOOT_COMPLETED is received twice, instead limit broadcast to your package only:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.package
```

Comment: For a strange fun, I copied the command without adding my package name, hoping that I could see some apps "really" misbehaving. It killed almost every other apps and somewhat rebooted the device. Worth it... :)

Comment: The -p option errors for me and http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#IntentSpec doesn't mention it?

Comment: Not all Android versions supported -p, you can try -n package_name/class_name

Answer (score 8):

On my Lollipop x86 emulator on Qemu, it required me to run as root:

`adb shell su root am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

Without root, the command fails: alarm manager does not send the broadcast:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=26595, uid=2000
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3537)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:772)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:404)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using flavors, be careful with the `.` component name shortcut notation.

*Example*

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.companyname.develop/com.companyname.notification.RescheduleLocalNotificationsAtBootReceiver
```

Answer (score -1):

To restart the emulator just open your command line and switch to folder where your adb is (if not in system path) and enter:

```
adb restart
```

(then you can abort the command with Strg - C to get cmd line back)

Comment: `adb reboot` works, `adb restart`: adb: usage: unknown command restart