# adb reboot broadcast doesn't work on some app

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325920/how-to-test-boot-completed-broadcast-receiver-in-emulator) question to test reboot broadcast of my own app.
i.e.,

```
C:\Eclipse\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell am broadcast -a
 android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME
 -n my.own.app/.BRAutoStart Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] cmp=my.own.app/.BRAutoStart }



 Broadcast completed: result=0
```

but it doesn't work.

The simple command reboots the device:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c
android.intent.category.HOME
```

I know that broadcast receiver BRAutoStart receives the `boot_completed` , because i've tested it and using it in production code.

I'm using the real device, not an emulator.

How to setup command line to send the broadcast to the device?

Comment: It may be because only the system may send this specific action : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.".

Comment: @YogeshRathi lol this question is much earlier created

Comment: @Vyacheslav , i agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this call:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n your.app.packagename/.YourReceiverClassName
```

it won't reboot your device but send broadcast to your receiver

Comment: I send the same request in the question. Read it more carefully.