# Android app doesn't start at system boot

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I've a reciever

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);
    }
}
```

and have modified the AndroidManifest.xml, adding these lines

```
<receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

to  section.
The application still does not start on system boot..any ideas appreciated. At least how can I monitor what is going on after device reboot (because I cant just use breakpoints in that case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag when starting activity from `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
myStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325920/how-to-test-boot-completed-broadcast-receiver-in-emulator) is how you can test the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I bet that you are right ... but without logcat's log it just a blind guess

Comment: Thanks, that was the needed line

Comment: @ArtemChauzov Please accept the answer if the issue is resolved.