# Receiver on BOOT_COMPLETED not fired

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to run some code on BOOT_COMPLETED intent with no luck. here is what i have try:

myreciever:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using onesentiment.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Plugin.LocalNotifications;
using Android.Widget;

namespace onesentiment
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.onesentiment.name.BootBroadcastReceiver", Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class BootUpReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        List<TaskReminder> CurrentTaskReminders = new List<TaskReminder>();

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "OnReceive", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Intent.ActionBootCompleted", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                if (Settings.TaskReminderList != string.Empty)
                    CurrentTaskReminders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TaskReminder>>(Settings.TaskReminderList);

                // Set up notification icon if necessary
                var resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField("ic_launcher").GetValue(null);
                LocalNotificationsImplementation.NotificationIconId = resourceId;

                // Retrieve notifications and cancel/resend them.
                if (CurrentTaskReminders.Count() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CurrentTaskReminders.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show(
                            context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.SetReminders_ReminderTitle),
                            context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.SetReminders_ReminderMessage), 
                            CurrentTaskReminders[i].CrossLocalNotificationID, 
                            CurrentTaskReminders[i].Date );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on manifest i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.onesentiment.name" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:label="onesentiment" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <receiver android:name="com.onesentiment.name.BootBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="com.onesentiment.name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

i'm getting **Settings.TaskReminderList** from sharedpreferences.

I'm not getting any Toast and the notifications from **CrossLocalNotifications** are not showing. if i don't restart the phone they work.

**EDIT:** im getting the following error:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED pkg=com.onesentiment.name}
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=9941, uid=2000
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3605)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:780)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:410)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:124)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:359)
```

For the Boot Completed permission i have just include it on my manifest. i don't have any additional code about this permission, is this the problem?

**EDIT2:**
after running the command adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED com.onesentiment.name on the emulator i get this (and the emulator doesn't restart):

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 2417):
D/AndroidRuntime( 2417): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 2417): CheckJNI is OFF
E/cutils-trace( 2417): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/memtrack( 2417): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 2417): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 2417): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime( 2417): Shutting down VM
```

Comment: Remove the `category` from the boot receiver. Also I would change the toasts to a logcat (`Log.XXXX`). Then rebuild/install the app, run it once, kill it, and then use adb to test : `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED com.onesentiment.name`

Comment: @SushiHangover i have update my question with the output im getting after firing your command

Comment: You have to run `adb root` first then... not sure you you are running a production build or not... emulator or not... take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325920/how-to-test-boot-completed-broadcast-receiver-in-emulator

Comment: im using a debug build on a real device

Comment: Unless that device is rooted, you'll just have to manually reboot it to test :-( ...so reboot it, and monitor logcat for your receiver output (assuming you are using `Log.XXXX` statements....

Comment: oh, what a sea of statements :P, will try to find mine

Comment: Filter it by tag, `adb logcat -s TheTagYouUsedINYourCode`

Comment: im using this log: Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug , "onesentiment", "OnReceive"); im not getting anything from logcat when i use adb logcat -s onesentiment

Comment: @SushiHangover i have run the adb shell command on an emulator and i have write the respond i have get ot the EDIT2 section on the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to go to Settings/ Applications/ MyApp and enable autostart. So it's not a problem with my code. It's a security issue that some phones have like Xiaomi Redmi phones

Comment: I don't know how it is working for you since the "android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" " tag is missing in your Android Manifest in Receiver tag.

Comment: @AZ_ it is not missing

Comment: How is this even a thing? Seriously 2022 problem still not resovled!